# axis2 1.6.1 vs rampart 1.6.0 compatibility

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, rampart

are these two versions compatible?

I get the following exception when deploying the policy-samples:

```
INFO main 2011-09-13 08:17:45.150 The SecureTokenService service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.findAssertionBuilderTarget(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.invokeBuilder(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:128)
at org.apache.neethi.AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.build(AssertionBuilderFactoryImpl.java:110)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:225)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getAllOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:185)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:218)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getExactlyOneOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:181)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.processOperationElement(PolicyBuilder.java:216)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicyOperator(PolicyBuilder.java:175)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyBuilder.getPolicy(PolicyBuilder.java:125)
at org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(PolicyEngine.java:102)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.processPolicyElements(DescriptionBuilder.java:639)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:307)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:370)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
at com.groiss.ws.axis2.deployment.Deployer.loadServices(Deployer.java:176)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
at com.groiss.ws.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:445)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:768)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:589)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
at com.groiss.httpd.jetty7.JettyService.startup(JettyService.java:305)
at com.groiss.httpd.jetty7.JettyService.startup(JettyService.java:74)
at com.groiss.httpd.jetty.Jetty.startup(Jetty.java:38)
at com.groiss.component.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:284)
at com.groiss.component.ServiceManager.main(ServiceManager.java:132)
at com.groiss.component.ServiceManager.main(ServiceManager.java:72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these versions are not compatible. There will be a Rampart 1.6.1 release soon.